# Regex not working for asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, regex, webforms

I want to validate phone for general phone numbers like

```
    (123) 456 7899
    (123).456.7899
    (123)-456-7899
    123-456-7899
    123 456 7899
    1234567899
    +123456789
```

This is a jquery regex `/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/` but it is not working with asp.net regularvalidator control.

What i need to change so that it will allow `-+ .() and numbers only`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Does the regex fail valid numbers? Pass invalid numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match the phone numbers which are delimited by `,.)(+`

```
^[-) .(+]?[0-9]{3}(?:[-) .(+]+)?[0-9]{3}(?:[-) .(+]+)?[0-9]{3,4}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1eW6/4)

OR

If you don't want to match the start or end, then you could use the below regex to match the phone-numbers which are loacted anywhere.

```
[-).(+]?[0-9]{3}(?:[-) .(+]+)?[0-9]{3}(?:[-) .(+]+)?[0-9]{3,4}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1eW6/5)